F40: Wifi Connected but no internet access
I've been having this problem with only one WIFI network for some time. My network card connects to the AP, manages to get both the IP address and the route, but I can't navigate. This is the result of the dmesg when connecting. If I connect to any other wifi everything works normally. Having dual boot with Windows, if I try to connect to the network that gives problems this time everything works normally, with the same IP addresses and route
[  239.062716] wlo1: authenticate with XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX (local address=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX)
[  239.063120] wlo1: send auth to XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX (try 1/3)
[  239.101920] wlo1: authenticated
[  239.102120] wlo1: associate with XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX (try 1/3)
[  239.114705] wlo1: RX AssocResp from XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX (capab=0x1511 status=0 aid=3)
[  239.116941] wlo1: associated
[  239.145834] wlo1: Limiting TX power to 23 (23 - 0) dBm as advertised by c4:b8:b4:da:16:10
[  239.160821] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Unhandled alg: 0xc0400707


Try this https://askubuntu.com/a/1209048

@ArtemS.Tashkinov tried but doesn't work

Try installing kernel 6.9.1 and the latest firmware files.

@ArtemS.Tashkinov can this be a driver issue? How? The OP said "If I connect to any other wifi everything works normally", which suggests that the drivers and everything else are working fine, right? Can a driver problem cause issues with just one network? I am no networking expert, not even close, but doesn't this sound more like a name resolution issue?

@user2098675 can you ping sites by IP? Can you [edit] your question and add the output of ping -c1 8.8.8.8 and ping -c1 google.com?

@terdon Can a driver problem cause issues with just one network? Yes, it's quite possible.

In case you feel like explaining, @ArtemS.Tashkinov, I posted a question since I'm curious about how such a thing could happen.
